# Value-Pairs in Snowflake: variant or object?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We want to store value-pairs as semi-structured data types in Snowflake.

It looks like we could use either OBJECT or VARIANT datatype.

The documentation implies to use OBJECT for value-pairs but is not too clear as whether it is a "better" choice than Variant... Or I missed it (very possible)

So... OBJECT or VARIANT?

Update: 
So far, we have started with a column of type OBJECT that we populate with JSON.
However, our JSON is simply value-pairs where the key name is never NULL.

Comment: Great question, and I wish to add:
If I'm sure that the data is a JSON, it is more performing the use of VARIANT COLUMN or the OBJECt COLUMN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what kind of data you want to store in your table / column it's hard to answer. 
You could easily store an OBJECT in a VARIANT column but not the opposite way. 
When you store an OBJECT you have to ensure that the key is not empty. 
("OBJECTS: Used to represent collections of key-value pairs, where the key is a non-empty string, and the value is a value of VARIANT type. Snowflake does not currently support explicitly-typed objects.")
More information can be found here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html

If you would like to store JSON in your variant column you could directly query it or using a FLATTEN command to present it more table like.

Comment: Although we are only using value-pairs, we have actually used PARSE_JSON() to populate our OBJECT columns.  
Yet it looks like we can use FLATTEN too...  
A bit confused...

Comment: Another way to ask my question could be...

Given that we only want to store value-pairs, is there any drawback in using OBJECT columns rather than VARIANT?

Comment: The drawback is always the relation of query cost over flexibility. When you know that you're limit your use case to value-pairs why not using simple columns for that? 
That would be the fastest and cheapest way to query, supported by the meta data managed for the table / micro-partitions.

Comment: We do not know the name of the value keys... This must remain dynamic, hence VARIANT or OBJECT

Comment: You mean like a triple store?

Comment: the flatten function can be used with all 3 semi-structured data:
FLATTEN is a table function that produces a lateral view of a VARIANT, OBJECT, or ARRAY column
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-flatten.html

Answer (score 1):

For name/value pairs, OBJECT is sufficient.  For example, `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('name',42)`.  VARIANT allows you to store other data types as well.

Comment: We are not planning to have more complex objects.